# Symfony FileLoaderLoadException but class does exist

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I've been using Symfony 3 since yesterday but are having a hard time with the auto-wiring.

For some reason the FileLoader can't find my class while it does exist.

In the services.yml I have the following:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true

    RideShare\Infrastructure\:
        resource: '../../src/RideShare/Infrastructure/*'
```

In the folder `src/RideShare/Infrastructure/EventStore/Doctrine` is have the file `DoctrineEventStore.php` with the following contents:

```
<?php

namespace RideShare\Infrastructure\EventStore\Doctrine;

use ...;

class DoctrineEventStore extends EntityRepository implements EventStore
```

But when I try to run `php bin/console` I'm getting the following exception:

```
Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException: 
Expected to find class "RideShare\Infrastructure\EventStore\Doctrine\DoctrineEventStore" in file "[....]src/RideShare/Infrastructure/EventStore/Doctrine/DoctrineEventStore.php" while importing services from resource 
"../../src/RideShare/Infrastructure/*", but it was not found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource in [...]/app/config/services.yml (which is being imported from "[...]/app/config/config.yml"). in [...]/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/FileLoader.php on line 179
```

For what I see this declaration is correct, I don't see questions like this on stackoverflow or in the Symfony documentation and I have no clue why it's failing.

Full code can be found at [Github](https://github.com/cwdt/ride-share-demo/tree/feature/event-store).

Comment: Did you try to reset the php-cli opcache?

Comment: I'm running in CGI mode without opcache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the EventStore interface had a wrong namespace.

Comment: @NiketPathak after some further debugging it appeared that the namespace of the EventStore was wrong (so the interface the DoctrineEventStore implemented)